# Create new column with data that has same column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame similat to this. How to add new column with names of rows that have same value in one of the column? For example:

Have this:

```
  name  building 
  a     blue
  b     white
  c     blue
  d     red
  e     blue
  f     red
```

How to get this?

```
  name  building  in_building_with
  a     blue      [c, e]
  b     white     []
  c     blue      [a, e]
  d     red       [f]
  e     blue      [a, c]
  f     red       [d]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is approach(worst) I can only think of :

```
r = df.groupby('building')['name'].agg(dict)
df['in_building_with'] = df.apply(lambda  x: [r[x['building']][i] for i in (r[x['building']].keys()-[x.name])], axis=1)
```

---

**df:**

```
name    building    in_building_with
0   a   blue    [c, e]
1   b   white   []
2   c   blue    [a, e]
3   d   red     [f]
4   e   blue    [a, c]
5   f   red     [d]
```

---

**Approach:**

1. Make a dictionary which will give your indices where the building occurs.

---

```
building
blue     {0: 'a', 2: 'c', 4: 'e'}
red              {3: 'd', 5: 'f'}
white                    {1: 'b'}
dtype: object
```

---

2. subtract the index of the current building from the list since you are looking at the element other than it to get the indices of appearance.

---

```
r[x['building']].keys()-[x.name]
```

---

3. Get the values at those indices and make them into a list.

Answer (score 4):

If order is not important, you could do:

```
# create groups
groups = df.groupby('building').transform(dict.fromkeys).squeeze()

# remove value from each group
df['in_building_with'] = [list(group.keys() - (e,)) for e, group in zip(df['name'], groups)]

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
  name building in_building_with
0    a     blue           [e, c]
1    b    white               []
2    c     blue           [e, a]
3    d      red              [f]
4    e     blue           [a, c]
5    f      red              [d]
```

Answer (score 2):

May be a little late but this is more concise way and **without** iterating over objects(for-loops).

*With thanks to @Pygirl answer and as an improvement to it:*

```
r = df.groupby('building')['name'].agg(set)
df['in_building_with']= df.apply( lambda x: list(r[x['building']] - {x['name']}) , axis=1)

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
    name building in_building_with
0    a     blue           [e, c]
1    b    white               []
2    c     blue           [e, a]
3    d      red              [f]
4    e     blue           [a, c]
5    f      red              [d]
```

Comment: Neat! Thanks for sharing the answer. Merry Christmas in advance :)

Comment: Thanks. Merry Christmas :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's use *boolean indexing* with `loc` inside a `list comprehension` to get the `names` from the rows that have same value of `building`:

```
df['in_building_with'] = [
    [*df.loc[df['building'].eq(y) & df['name'].ne(x), 'name']] for x, y in df.to_numpy()]
```

Result:

```
  name building in_building_with
0    a     blue           [c, e]
1    b    white               []
2    c     blue           [a, e]
3    d      red              [f]
4    e     blue           [a, c]
5    f      red              [d]
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
# creating an extra column in the data frame
df['in_building_with'] = "";
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   data = []
   # below line will return the index that has the same color as that of row
   buildingList = df[df['building'] == row['building']].index.tolist();
   for i in buildingList:
      # the list also contains the current row index, hence adding a check below
      if(df['name'][i] != row['name']):
          data.append(df['name'][i]);
   df['in_building_with'][index] = data;

print(df)
```

Result:

```
  name building in_building_with
0    a     blue           [c, e]
1    b    white               []
2    c     blue           [a, e]
3    d      red              [f]
4    e     blue           [a, c]
5    f      red              [d]
```